# What's wrong in this loop?

Tags: php

I checked and i don't found errors:

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = 2 
$preparado[1] = "Miguel";
$preparado[2] = "Carlos";
$segundo[1]= "Beltran";
$segundo[2] = "Sanz";

for($i = 1; $i <=$_SESSION['variable']; $i++){
  $listo[$i] = $preparado1[$i] . $segundo[1];
}


for($i = ($_SESSION['variable'] + 1) ; $i <= ($_SESSION['variable'] * 2); $i++){
  for($n = 1; $n <=$_SESSION['variable']; $n++){
    $listo[$i] = $preparado1[$n] . $segundo[2];
  }
}

for($i = 1;$i <=$_SESSION['variable'] * $_SESSION['extension']; $i++ ){
  echo   $final[$i] . "</br>";
}
```

I  recibe this:

```
MiguelBeltran
CarlosBeltran
CarlosSanz
CarlosSanz
```

But I should recibe this:

```
MiguelBeltran
CarlosBeltran
MiguelSanz
CarlosSanz
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you intended

```
$preparado[0] = "Miguel"; // rather than [1]
$preparado[1] = "Carlos";
```

Comment: The real trouble comes from your nested `for` loops. The first goes from i+1 to i*2 - that's fine (a bit unusual, but it works). However, *for every possible value of i* you iterate through all values *n* ranging from 1 to the `variable`. Considering how you store the result, I'm quite sure that this is not what you intended. So keep checking your loop logic.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not consistent with the output you presented:

1. There's no way you get a `Miguel` in your output as you do:

   ```
   $preparado[1] = "Miguel";
   $preparado[1] = "Carlos";
   ```

   so the only variable you assign `Miguel` to, is overwritten the next line.
2. There is no variable `$preparado1`.

You should post the code you actually used to generate the output you got.

Comment: It's an typografy error, but in the original code this is right because is generated by another loop.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
$_SESSION['variable'] = 2 
$preparado[1] = "Miguel";
$preparado[2] = "Carlos";
$segundo[1]= "Beltran";
$segundo[2] = "Sanz";
```

Use:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $_SESSION['variable']; ++$i) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $_SESSION['variable']; ++$j) {
        $listo[] = $preparado[$j].$segundo[$i];
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, and $listo[] should continue with the first loop, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$preparado[1] = "Miguel";
$preparado[1] = "Carlos";
$segundo[1]= "Beltran";
$segundo[2] = "Sanz";
```

You assigned `$preparado[1]` twice.

Comment: It's an typografy error, but in the original code this is right because is generated by another loop.